# extracting flv video from RAM dump

Tags: ram, flash-video, computer-forensics

I want to extract some FLV video from a RAM dump. Is there an easy way to do that using some good tool you know about?
I've Googled but I found nothing!

I have an idea to do that but it seems difficult and time-consuming, I'll search for FLV magic number and start to extract the data incrementally from there, but I don't know if this method works actually.

Comment: Are you looking for some library? For which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Macintosh FileJuicer program does what you describe (search binary blobs for magic numbers and extract), it would search the RAM dump for all magic numbers it knows about, I'm not sure if there's an equivelant for other OSes perhaps one that's open source, but at least it's one more google search term.